# Autodesk Revit Assembly

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk

If I have geometry from some other source like Inventor how can I import it into Revit as an assembly? I do not want to import it as a family because currently using Revit 2022 it just imports the geoemerty as a "dumb" block and I cannot make any manual edits if needed before pushing that data back out of revit.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, imported objects are not editable in Revit as I know. If you want to make inventor models editable in Revit, you need to follow the **Workflow 2 Configurable assembly** of [Inventor to Revit Family File (RFA) Workflow](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/inventor/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/Inventor-Help/files/GUID-D20CD536-0577-4253-BE0E-F07508BE1E81-htm.html) to export as Revit family (RFA). In addition, there is no Revit API to achieve this. Sorry for the bad news.

However, this question sounds not like a problem of neither a Revit API nor Forge. Please ask here: https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-products/ct-p/2003